# Dynamically change value of in an XSL file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Currently the displaying the XML in a browser along with the XSL data is correct except for one thing. In some colleges I have one department while in orders I have more than one (up to 9). How I can dynamically output the data based on the number of department for each college? Currently it only outputs one department per college.

College.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="colleges.xsl"?><colleges>
<college id="0">
<school>College of Education</school>
<mission>text</mission>
<department id="0">Educational Psychology and Leadership</department>
<department id="1">Health and Human Performance</department>
<department id="2">Language, Literacy and Intercultural Studies</department>
<department id="3">Teaching, Learning and Innovation</department>
</college>
<college id="1">
<school>College of Nursing</school>
<mission>text</mission>
<department id="0">Nursing</department>
</college>
<college id="2">
<school>School of Business</school>
<mission>text</mission>
<department id="0">Accounting and Management Information Systems</department>
<department id="1">Applied Business Technology</department>
</college></colleges>
```

College.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:for-each select="colleges/college">
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="school"/></span> - <br /><xsl:value-of select="mission"/>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="department"/><br />
        </p>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Rather then letting us guess, you should post the exact output that you expect to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="/"> ...
    <xsl:for-each select="colleges/college">
      ...
        <xsl:apply-templates select="department"/>
       ...
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 
<xsl:template match="department">... what you want for each department</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:for-each select="colleges/college">
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="school"/></span> - <br /><xsl:value-of select="mission"/>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="department"/>
        </p>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="department">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
</xsl:template>
```